# How to put translator in Zend2 form

Tags: zend-framework2

Iam new guy to Zend framework and currently Iam working on Zend2...I want to ask about Translator usage in Zend forms....If i want to use translator i directly using for labels in form view i.e.form_view.php like

```
$this->formLabel()->setTranslator($translator, 'date_of_birth');
```

But I want to add the translator at the form only i.e.in src/my_module/Form/UserForm.php
like

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'date_of_birth',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id' => 'date_of_birth',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'DateOfBirth',
        ),                                 //Here there is any option to put translator
    ));
```

Please help me...any answer would be help for me like I asked

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://techie.ayyappadas.com/how-do-use-poeditor

Comment: Yes @ubercooluk I know po editor and I have used it in my VIEW .phtml files but I want it add it in form( like src/my_module/Form/UserForm.php) not in form view

Comment: @Gautam3164 I don't see how my answer no longer answers your question. It does **exactly** what you asked for. Whether it is good practice or not is not my problem as an answerer. If you don't want an answer to what you are asking, perhaps you shouldn't ask the question.

Comment: Gautam3164 you opened up a bounty in hoped for better answers. Apparently no answer matched your criteria. Could you please provide some feedback as to what is missing within those answers for you? As to what i can see two approaches (mine and @Andy0708) have been presented to you that have the same outcome with different strategies. Why don't they match what you are looking for, what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do that. Since the the Translator that is set up using the factory-key `translator` will automatically be injected into the Form.

The best approach (in my opinion) is to make extensive use of the translator `text_domain`:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'        => 'phparray',
            'base_dir'    => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'     => '%s.php',
            'text_domain' => 'MyModuleTextDomain'
        ),
    ),
),
```

With this setup, the Files of your Module will automatically be inserted into the default TranslatorService which every Zend\Form knows of.

So ultimately all you have to do is make the `ViewHelpers` know of the `TextDomain` that you are using. And this is done in the following manner:

```
$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('MyModuleTextDomain');
$this->formButton()->setTranslatorTextDomain('MyModuleTextDomain');
$this->formElementErrors()->setTranslatorTextDomain('MyModuleTextDomain');
```

You need to do this once inside your respective `view.phtml` before(!) using the ViewHelpers like `$this->formElement($element)` or `$this->formCollection($form)`

And that's really all there is to it. I recall having seen a discussion somewhere about making it easier to pass along Text-Domain-Data, but i can't find it right now. So things may get a little easier in the future ;) For now, 3 lines are all that's needed though!

Answer (score 1):

above answer is quite unnecessary ... as your translator was added automatically to zend form for rendering form labels and ....
only use this code in your module config :

```
'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'phparray',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.php',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

if u use the correct view helpers for rendering form elements (or whole form) it will automatically translated

Comment: He asked how to add the translator to his form, and I told him exactly how to do that. I even stated in my answer that it is probably not a good idea. Nevertheless, it is what he asked for. I am not going to second guess his intensions for doing it.

Comment: I would vote for this approach, too, but it's highly encouraged to use `text_domain`s. Especially when it comes to forms, similar naming conventions may result in different translations. Using a Text-Domain you can be sure that YOUR Translation will not be overwritten by another module (as long as the text_domain is somewhat unique)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a recommended approach because forms are translated automatically if you have a translator configured (which you do if you are using the Skeleton Application). However, since you asked how to use the translator directly within your form, I will show you how you can do it. Please carefully consider if you really want to do this, as I cannot imagine a use case where it would be necessary.**

To do exactly what you were asking, you can inject the translator into your form. You can do this either in your controller or in a factory. I will be using a factory in this example because it is more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
// In your module's config file
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'YourModule\Form\YourForm' => function($sm) {
            $translator = $sm->get('Translator');
            return new \YourModule\Form\YourForm($translator);
        },
    ),
),
```

Then in your form class, you can do like this:

```
namespace YourModule\Form;

class RegisterForm extends \Zend\Form\Form {
    public function __construct($translator) {
        // Do something

        $translated_string = $translator->translate('string to translate');
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, you can do like this:

`$your_form = $this->servicelocator->get('YourModule\Form\YourForm');`

Or if you don't want to use the factory, you can choose to not add it and do like this instead:

`$your_form = new \YourModule\Form\YourForm($this->servicelocator->get('Translator'));`

I would recommend going with the factory, though.